# How to access iCarousel item view data?

Tags: icarousel

Whether, it is possible to retrieve iCarousel particular item data based on iCarousel currentItemIndex? (ie) Suppose I have 10 items in iCarousel, each item having an UILabel. I want to access 3 item UILabel text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using itemViewAtIndex: to get the item view and look in its subviews to find the label.

That's the wrong approach though, you shouldn't store data in your item views. You must have originally set that label from your data source, so to find out the label text for a given index, just retrieve it from your model again (which is presumably an array of some sort).